# Have I found a bug in Python's str.endswith()?

Tags: python, string

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

> str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])
>
> Return True if the string ends with the specified suffix, otherwise return False. suffix can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for. With optional start, test beginning at that position. Withoptional end, stop comparing at that position.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Accept tuples as suffix.

The following code should return `True`, but it returns `False` in Python 2.7.3:

```
"hello-".endswith(('.', ',', ':', ';', '-' '?', '!'))
```

It seems `str.endswith()` ignores anything beyond the forth tuple element:

```
>>> "hello-".endswith(('.', ',', ':', '-', ';' '?', '!'))
>>> True
>>> "hello;".endswith(('.', ',', ':', '-', ';' '?', '!'))
>>> False
```

Have I found a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Implicit string literal concatenation strikes again!

Comment: @user2357112: yep, it was a danger when we added it to C, and it still bites people even in these newer languages. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> or am I missing something?

You're missing a comma after the `';'` in your tuple:

```
>>> "hello;".endswith(('.', ',', ':', '-', ';' '?', '!'))
                                         #    ^
                                         # comma missing
False
```

Due to this, `;` and `?` are concatenated. So, the string ending with `;?` will return `True` for this case:

```
>>> "hello;?".endswith(('.', ',', ':', '-', ';' '?', '!'))
True
```

After adding a comma, it would work as expected:

```
>>> "hello;".endswith(('.', ',', ':', '-', ';', '?', '!'))
True
```

Comment: D'oh! Can't believe I missed that! Why doesn't it throw a syntax error?

Comment: @SeanW.. String literals sitting adjacent to each other are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

If you write tuple as

```
>>> tuple_example = ('.', ',', ':', '-', ';' '?', '!')
```

then the tuple will become

```
>>> tuple_example
('.', ',', ':', '-', ';?', '!')
                          ^
                   # concatenate together
```

So that is why return False

Answer (score 0):

It has already been pointed out that adjacent string literals are concatenated, but I wanted to add a little additional information and context.

This is a feature that is shared with (and borrowed from) C.

Additionally, this is doesn't act like a concatenation operator like '+', and is treated identically as if they were literally joined together in the source without any additional overhead.

For example:

```
>>> 'a' 'b' * 2
'abab'
```

Whether this is useful feature or an annoying design is really a matter of opinion, but it does allow for breaking up string literals among multiple lines by encapsulating the literals within parentheses.

```
>>> print("I don't want to type this whole string"
          "literal all on one line.")
I don't want to type this whole stringliteral all on one line.
```

That type of usage (along with being used with #defines) is why it was useful in C in the first place and was subsequently brought along in Python.